# Tried doing dual boot but now I can't access either Windows or Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I see there are a lot of posts on this topic but I can't find anyone to answer my questions.

So I had Windows 10 installed with Legacy Bios and with a MBR partition table. I tried installing Ubuntu dual boot using [this](https://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/) guide but I did not see that it was for an UEFI Bios. During my installation it wanted me to create an EFI partition, and I'm quite new to Bios modes/partitioning etc. so I went along with it and created an EFI partition alongside my root, swap and home partitions. After finishing the installation I can't start either Ubuntu or Windows with both saying "Missing operating system".
When I go into "Try Ubuntu without installing" it seems that my Windows partitions sda1 and sda2 still exists. Shown here [GParted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUmhG.jpg).

What I'm thinking is that if I can remove Ubuntu and get Windows to work again, then I can run a new Ubuntu installation but this time with Legacy Bios.
My question is, if I delete the Ubuntu partitions, would my Windows start working again? And if so, is it just to press "delete" on the partitions when viewing in GParted? Or is there something else I should do?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to delete either system. Just to confirm the format status of your disk, if you open Gparted again, then click  *View->Device Information*. what is the description shown against *Partition Table*?

Comment: You can just delete the Ubuntu partitions from GParted but you need to be in the live environment (Try Ubuntu) to do that. You will need to turn swap off to get rid of the swap partition. A new install will normally create a swap file. You don’t need a swap partition. I’d guess a Legacy Windows install would still work after that but maybe not.

Comment: I disagree with @Paul Benson. You cannot get dual booting from grub when one os is in Legacy mode and the other is UEFI

Comment: What are you disagreeing about? You're talking rubbish.

Comment: To @PaulBenson, here is the [Device Information](https://imgur.com/8CPk5Ms)

Comment: To @PonJar, if I delete the partitions as you propose, are you saying that I will need to reinstall Windows from f.ex. an USB? Would be preferable if my old Windows would just start working again without having to reinstall Windows.

Comment: If I were you I would aim to have both OS boot in Legacy mode from grub. I would therefore delete all the Ubuntu partitions including the extended sda3 partition. I would install Ubuntu into the space created, but don’t use a swap partition. The default is a swap file. I would use a single partition for / and /home since you don’t have much space at all. It’s hard to predict how much space to give each partition although I understand why you might want to have /home separate. Ubuntu should then work and Windows may work. If not you should be able to fix that.

Comment: @Paul Benson I was disagreeing with your first sentence. “ You don't need to delete either system.” I don’t believe you can get dual booting from grub when one os is in Legacy mode and the other is UEFI. Therefore at least one needs to be deleted and reinstalled. It would seem logical to reinstall Ubuntu in Legacy mode since this was a new install with no significant user data in /home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've dug a bit of a hole for yourself here. You basically need to convert your disk from an MBR format to a GPT one as you now have an ESP boot-up which will only work with Win10 on a GPT disk. Trouble is if you convert this from Live Ubuntu using Gparted you wipe your disk. And as you can't boot into Win10 to do this where you won't have to wipe your disk you're caught between a rock and a hard place. However there is a solution without wiping your disk.

First you need to backup your data From Live Ubuntu mount sda2, which I presume is your Windows *C:\ drive*. The command is `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt`. Then navigate to /mnt (by Nautilus) and find your data files/folders and copy them over to an external drive. When done, you'll need a PE version of Windows. If you made an installation disk/USB drive for Win10 you're in luck. If not, you'll need to make a [Win10 Recovery disk](https://uk.pcmag.com/how-to/116253/how-to-revive-windows-10-with-a-recovery-drive) which can also be done on a USB drive by borrowing someone's Win10 machine and make one from there. This will enable you to boot into the USB drive and convert your disk to GPT externally without loss of data using Window's [GPTGEN command](https://www.techdim.com/convert-mbr-gpt-without-losing-data/).

If that all seems a bit daunting, the easier but longer method is to convert to GPT using Gparted, switching from BIOS Legacy mode to UEFI then re-installing Win10 and Ubuntu as your disk gets wiped during the conversion. But that will take a lot longer  with all the updates and possible app re-installs.

Comment: Just to check, if I delete my ESP boot partition that won't fix my problem and revert it back to whatever boot-up that was used prior? There never was any boot-up partitions before installing Ubuntu so was hoping that it might revert back

Comment: If you delete your ESP you'll have nothing to boot from for either system. The recovery USB for Win10 is a very useful tool to have, in fact I'd say it's essential as Windows can go awry in various ways and you can use it to restore your system. Meanwhile you could try switching your BIOS to UEFI and see if you can boot to Ubuntu, but really you need to convert disk to GPT. An ESP partition for Ubuntu recognises MBR disks as well as GPT. For Windows it does not.

Comment: I tried booting to Ubuntu to check but it does not work. I just get "Reboot and Select proper Boot device".
This is what my BIOS looks like and the second image shows all the boot options. None of them working. https://imgur.com/a/gDRVBeO

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did a disk backup of the C:\ drive(sda2) before installing Ubuntu. If I have done that can I skip the step about saving all the files from sda2.
Backup was done by Aomei https://www.aomeitech.com/aomei-backupper.html which gave me an 158GB .adi file. Tho I'm not sure how to use an .adi file. The sda2 disk is around 160GB when I view it in GParted.

Comment: I don't use Aomei. so can't help you there except it seems you took an image of the whole partition. You need to backup data separately from your system. If you mount the drive as suggested you can find the data files and copy them independently. Do you have data files on sda2. Ubuntu should be first priority in UEFI booting order. This is getting beyond the scope of Ubuntu as your problem is in the area of UEFI/firmware and Windows rather than Ubuntu itself.

Comment: I ended up doing a full wipe and reinstalling both Windows and Ubuntu. Transferred all my files first through the Live USB "Try Ubuntu" -> Mount old disk and external hard drive -> and transferred files with rsync. Thank you for the help Paul!

Edit: Tried deleting all the Ubuntu partitions before doing the full wipe/reinstall but Windows would still not load.